# What would be the Go structs for this terse JSON document?

Tags: json, go

The document has minimal key/value pair metadata on purpose.  In a list of people, we could have something like `"name":"joe"` or we could have a key of `joe`.  It errs on having fewer keys.

Perhaps this document is just too dynamic for Go structs?  I've tried YAML as well, it's the structs that's the problem.  The structs remain empty because it's not mapping correctly.

Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/PGSjoKvNja

Or do I need to roll my own UnmarshalJSON and have conditionals (or switch) for "actions"?  That's fine if so.  I could do coercion and validation in there, loop through the doc and detect what the problematic *generic action* bit is and then create a struct of the right type.

Comment: Structs are strongly typed, so to unmarshal to a struct, the data must be consistent. If the data is not consistent, you might be better off unmarshalling into a map.

Comment: I'm trying to make this pretty flexible so I was looking at HCL and mapstructure.  I don't know yet if these are more what I want.  Check out the `Extra` field in this example: https://godoc.org/github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure#example-Decode

Answer (score 1):

If the data is **NOT** consistent, as @Adrian stated, you should not go for what I'm showing.

Otherwise, you should be able to unmarshal your string with the following struct generated with [json-to-go](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/), a very useful tool to get a struct out of a json

```
type Custom struct {
    Ball []struct {
        Throw struct {
            Strength string `json:"strength"`
        } `json:"throw"`
    } `json:"ball"`
    Frisbee []struct {
        Fling struct {
            Curve string `json:"curve"`
        } `json:"fling"`
        Catch struct {
            Trick string `json:"trick"`
            Jump string `json:"jump"`
        } `json:"catch"`
    } `json:"frisbee"`
}
```

And then

```
func main() {

    var c Custom
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &c )
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

     fmt.Println(input)

}
```

Which prints out

```
{
    "ball": [{
        "throw": {
            "strength": "60%"
        }
    }, {
        "throw": {
            "strength": "20%"
        }
    }],
    "frisbee": [{
        "fling": {
            "curve": "left"
        }
    }, {
        "catch": {
            "trick": "behind back",
            "jump": "sure"
        }
    }]
}
```

Have a look at [this Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/xsce6B_oax) I set up.

Answer (score 1):

It would be:

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
    Ball []struct {
        Throw struct {
            Strength string `json:"strength"`
        } `json:"throw"`
    } `json:"ball"`
    Frisbee []struct {
        Fling struct {
            Curve string `json:"curve"`
        } `json:"fling,omitempty"`
        Catch struct {
            Trick string `json:"trick"`
            Jump string `json:"jump"`
        } `json:"catch,omitempty"`
    } `json:"frisbee"`
}
```

Ofcourse you can define a separate type for each inline struct definition. You can use [this](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) online tool (which is used for generating the above data structure).

Comment: Yeah, more types like this: https://play.golang.org/p/ZET8YE_ihX but then I have nils everywhere.  Which I could do a cleanup pass I guess?  I think my own JSON schema is pretty bad in this case.  It works in Ruby because Ruby doesn't care about types in a hash.  It just does it.  So maybe my schema habits are too dynamic or something.  I hope I can get the mapstructure pkg to work for me.

Comment: Well, I use Go not because of the language itself, but the workflow and tools (binary deployment, consistency in coding style via gofmt, etc etc). Go is never advertised as a break through in language design or expressiveness. In contrast with the promoted best practices in community, I do use lots of reflection and the like. In addition to `map[string]interface{}`, there are some bits inside `json` package such as `json.RawMessage` and two interfaces (`json.Marshaler` and `json.Unmarshaler`) that help with handling too dynamic situations.

Comment: Reference links:

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage
https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler
https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler

Comment: BTW you do not have to use pointers (in code snippet provided in play ground).